# Spring Controller 405 errors for POST request

Tags: spring, maven, post, http-status-code-405

I'm following this [Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/). It had a build error which I fixed by adding the following code in the POM.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3</version>
     <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The project is working fine as expected. Now I added a simple form which sends a post request to the controller. The search page looks like this

```
<form name='SearchForm' action="<c:url value='/search' />" method='POST'>
    <center>Search By Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><input type="Submit" name="action" value="Search"> </td></center>
</form>
```

The controller looks like this (Even when I hard code the search parameter, the request does not reach the controller)

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/search" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView searchUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("searchPage");
    model.addObject("userDTOList", userService.searchUser("sam"));
    return model;
}
```

I have the relevant service and modal and DAO classes to do a retrieval. If I change the request to be GET, it works as expected. But when I try POST method, I get 405 exception.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

What am I doing wrong in this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: That does not make and difference. I'm still getting the 405 exception.

Comment: @Visahan can you try with this code also in your searchpage.html: <input type="hidden"
name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
value="${_csrf.token}"/>

Comment: I tried that, and now it works Fine, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial uses **springSecurityFilterChain** with **CSRF** protection configured and
**Spring Security 3.2.3** so add the following to your ***searchpage.html***:

```
<input type="hidden"
name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```